# ArrayList sorting tournament placings

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Okay I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sort my data by tournament placings. Here is my code.

```java
if (o == 5) {
    double RD, t, old, x;
    String tournament, player;
    int a, number_of_players, place;
    place = 0;
    ArrayList<player> players = new ArrayList<player> ();
    ArrayList<placeDisplay> placeVar = new ArrayList<placeDisplay> ();
    List<placeDisplay> sort = new ArrayList<placeDisplay> ();

    System.out.println("1:Add a tournament \t2:View Existing");
    a = keyIn.nextInt();

    if (a == 1) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter tournament name");
        tournament = keyIn.next();
        System.out.println("\nEnter number of players");
        number_of_players = keyIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter players");

        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_players; i++) {
            String name = keyIn.next();
            player plr = new player();
            plr.setName(name);
            players.add(plr);
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter places for");
        System.out.println(players);

        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\n" + players.get(i));
            int places = keyIn.nextInt();
            placeDisplay placer = new placeDisplay();
            placer.setPlace(places);
            placeVar.add(placer);
        }

        Collections.sort(sort);
        System.out.println("\nThe Places are as follows");

        for (int i = 0; i < players.size() && i < placeVar.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(placeVar.get(i) + ":" + players.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

here is my public placeDisplay class file.

```java
public class placeDisplay implements Comparable<placeDisplay> {

    private int places;

    public void setPlace(int nPlace) {
        places = nPlace;
    }

    public int getPlace() {
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(places);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(placeDisplay placeDisplay){
        if (places > places)
            return 1;
        else if (places == places)
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Here is the public class file

```
 public class player {

private String name;

public void setName(String pName)
{
    name = pName;
}

public String getName()
{

    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

and here is my result on this portion of the program. Hope you guys can help me out on this one!

```
1:Add a tournament  2:View Existing
1

Enter tournament name
tournament1

Enter number of players
3
Enter players
Bob
Sally
John

Enter places for
[Bob, Sally, John]

Bob
2

Sally
1

John
3

The Places are as follows
2:Bob
1:Sally
3:John

Return to Main Menu? (Y/N)
```

Comment: Not a snippet. \*facepalm\*

Comment: Sorry I only joined the website a few hours ago and really don't know much about how it works. I couldn't get the results screen how I wanted so I just copied it into the snippet thinking it wouldn't matter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to **Modify your comparator method**.

```
public int compareTo(placeDisplay placeDisplay){
        if (places > placeDisplay.places)
            return 1;
        else if (places == placeDisplay.places)
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Somehow I'm getting the same result :/ any other thoughts?

Comment: @KevinLewis request you to please post the complete code, Player class, main method code.

Comment: main method is pretty long but I included the player class for you @ankur-singhal

Comment: @KevinLewis just understood your code now, seems to be wrong. You are doing ` Collections.sort(sort);` but you have not added anything in `sort`, Also both your `player` and `placeDisplay` are separate entities/pojo and you are maintaining two separate list, one you can sort on basis of ranking, and you are loopiong on both list with same index.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I just had to change my code to Collections.sort(placeDisplay);

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareTo` is not right because you are comparing the same variable.
Change it to:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(placeDisplay placeDisplay){
    if (places > placeDisplay.getPlace())
        return 1;
    else if (places == placeDisplay.getPlace())
        return 0;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Or even simply:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(placeDisplay placeDisplay){
    return places - placeDisplay.getPlace();
}
```

I also suggest you to overwrite the `equals` method to make it consistent with your `compareTo`, as recommended in the Comparable interface documentation: *"The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false."*.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions. The first did not work with .getPlace(); and the second and more simpler option unfortunately ended up with the same result :/ any further thoughts? Maybe my Collections.sort(sort); is misplaced?